# Eclipse: The type org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableBothMatcher cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: eclipse, maven, unit-testing, mockito, hamcrest

I was working on a unit testing for a `Spring MVC` controller using `TestNG` and `Mockito`. I've included `Hamcrest` library in the Maven dependencies as shown below. What am I missing here? The error shows up when I use the following two methods:

```
org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
```

The following are my dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

The problem has been resolved by changing `hamcrest-library` to `hamcrest-all`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As per suggested by Tunaki, the better solution would be to exclude the transitive dependency `hamcrest-core` from `mockito` library. So the final dependencies should look something like as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a dependency conflict in your POM:

- `mockito-core` 1.10.8 depends on `hamcrest-core` 1.1.
- `hamcrest-library` 1.3 depends on `hamcrest-core` 1.3.

Maven resolves the conflict by selecting version 1.1 ([it is declared first and they have equal path](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)).

You are getting this error because `hamcrest-library` 1.3 references the `CombinableMatcher` class [that did not exist in version 1.1](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/tree/hamcrest-java-1.1/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core) but [does exist in version 1.3](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/hamcrest-java-1.3/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/CombinableMatcher.java).

If you really depend on Hamcrest 1.3 specific features, you need to exclude `hamcrest-core` transitive dependency from `mockito-core` (and hope Hamcrest 1.3 is backwards compatible with 1.1). Otherwise, just remove `hamcrest-library` and you will then depend on Hamcrest 1.1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if it works or not. But the problem was gone when I replaced hamcrest-library with hamcrest-all. Thanks.

Comment: @ManojShrestha You didn't remove the problem actually, you just hid it. `hamcrest-all` is an uber-jar dependency that encapsulate all of Hamcrest dependencies (hamcrest-core and hamcrest-library). Since there is no actual dependency on hamcrest-core, Maven can't detect the conflict, but it is still there. The problem will likely come back, but at run-time now.

Comment: It didn't throw any run-time errors. But I think what you're saying makes more sense to me. I tried excluding hamcrest-core from mockito-core, it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for doing the research for me.